# All "echo gettype" in php are shown as string

Tags: php

I am making my first steps in PHP. The problems is I defined different types of variables, but the output shows their type as string.

Code

```
    $firstname = 'Hosam';
    $age = '22';
    $height = '1.84';
    $mobile = 'true';
            echo $firstname . '<br/>';
            echo gettype($firstname).'<br/>';
            echo $age . '<br/>';
            echo gettype($age).'<br/>';
            echo $height . '<br/>';
            echo gettype($height).'<br/>';
            if ($mobile) {echo 'i9300'.'<br/>';}
            else {echo 'Does not have smartphone'.'<br/>';}
            echo gettype($mobile);
```

Output

```
Hosam 
string
22
string
1.84
string
i9300
string
```

Comment: Simple: Because they are all strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP it's a string if you define it as so, until you do something that type juggles it, like add to it, or check it's truthyness.

You'll want to define them without the quotes, or cast them to explicitly change their type.

Read this for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the quotes from the numbers.

```
$firstname = 'Hosam';
$age = 22;
$height = 1.84;
$mobile = 'true';
```

any value that is in quotes is a string, even if its a number

so '22' is a string.

but 22 is a number.

And as Dan pointed out also. You will want to remove quotes around true, since true is not considered a string , unless you're actually wanting to like print the word true.

Comment: You could also remove the quotes around `true` to make it a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for responding :D